# My views slideshow doesn't work when the display is called from page.tpl.php

Tags: 6, views

I am working on Drupal 6.  I have a view with a display block.  My view contains an animation of 6 images with slideshow as Style.

If I put the block in the content the view works fine, the images changes.  However, when I call the same block from template the images not change, I can see only one image.   What is my error?

my code is:

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block', 'view', 'images_home-block_1');
print $block['content'];
?>
```

Also, I tried this code:

```
<?php 
print views_embed_view('images_home', $display_id = 'block_1'); 
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try your views block inside a theme region.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.  This solution works for me!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can try views_embed_view to call a views block programatically.

[views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/6)

```
<?php
print views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id, $argument); // with single argument
print views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id, array($arg1,$arg2,$arg3)); // with multiple arguments
?>
```

Comment: I have tried the follow code: <?php print views_embed_view('imagenes_home', $display_id = 'block_1'); ?>, and the view slideshow doesn't work.  Thanks for your answer and your help.

Answer (score 1):

Define variables on template.php

```
<?php
  function bluemarine_preprocess_page(&$variables) {   
      $variables['slideshow'] = views_embed_view('images_home', $display_id = 'block_1');     
  }
?>
```

Now you can print this variables on page.tpl

```
<?php

     print  $slideshow;     

?>
```